# Инспектор объектов для UserControl

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net

К созданному UserControl нужно добавить на форму инспектор объектов (для него).
Как мне сказали, его нужно "просто подключить". Который день не могу ничего найти (
Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: propertyGrid

Answer (score 1):

Так положите на форму PropertyGrid и задайте ему нужное свойство.